# How to add new Scope in ClientScopes table using IdentityServer4 with Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, identityserver4, openid-connect

I have configured IdentityServer4 for an authentication with Entity Framework Core in my application and have also added a few clients. I tried to add a new scope for any client in `ClientScopes` table. I was not able to add it from code level and also `ClientScopes` table does not exist in `ConfigurationDbContext`.

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Entities;
using IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Interfaces;
using IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Options;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.DbContexts
{
    public class ConfigurationDbContext : DbContext, IConfigurationDbContext, IDisposable
    {
        public ConfigurationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ConfigurationDbContext> options, ConfigurationStoreOptions storeOptions);

        public DbSet<ApiResource> ApiResources { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Client> Clients { get; set; }
        public DbSet<IdentityResource> IdentityResources { get; set; }

        public Task<int> SaveChangesAsync();
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

Can anyone please guide me how can I add a new scope to the existing clients?

Comment: FYI: ClientScopes does exist in the ConfigurationDbContext, it's just not exposed as a DbSet. Take a look on the Client object and you'll see it as a property.

Answer (score -1):

I suppose that you are using one of the quick starts? Am I right? If so - then you are using the `InMemory ApiResources`. They are configured in the `Startup.cs`:

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // configure identity server with in-memory stores, keys, clients and scopes
        services.AddIdentityServer()
            .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
            .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetApiResources())
            .AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients());
    }
```

Go to this `Config.GetApiResources()` (it is in `Config.cs` file) and there you can add the scopes that you need. Of course in your clients table, you should also add the scope to the allowed scopes for the client.

Comment: I can able to add a new scope to the Client AllowedScopes but it's not inserting on the ClientScopes table. Example: 
                AllowedScopes = {
                        StandardScopes.OpenId,
                        StandardScopes.Profile,
                        StandardScopes.OfflineAccess,
                        AppSettings.LSAPI
                    }

Comment: I'm creating access token using Identity server 4 for user authentication in my application. Example: using (var serviceScope = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope()){serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<PersistedGrantDbContext>().Database.Migrate();var context =serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ConfigurationDbContext>(); context.Database.Migrate();foreach (var client in Clients.GetClients()){if(context.Clients.Where(c=>c.ClientId.Equals(client.ClientId)).Count() == 0)context.Clients.Add(client.ToEntity());}context.SaveChanges();}